Broken OS when upgrading from 22.04
I can no longer get ubuntu-desktop to install after restarting my computer when it was stuck in a black screen for a long period during the upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04. Right now on boot it goes directly into the command line after login.
To note the command to fix broken install leads to dependency issues.


I'd suggest booting into a text terminal only, and ensuring your system has completed its release-upgrade BEFORE you attempt a GUI login. I'd start by running sudo apt update and read the output & ensure what is there is complete; without warnings/errors, no missing lines & correct codename etc.  Then sudo apt full-upgrade and maybe sudo apt -f install and follow the output to ensure all are clean without warning/messages etc. After that you can re-attempt a GUI login or attempt to re-install; but ensure everything is correct first; and read the messages

Trying sudo apt update yields  https://ibb.co/wKN714R

Try running the following:
sudo apt update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt -m install
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu desktop
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoremove

Repeat the chain of commands in case some of them give errors
